# automatic mysql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

How do i write a code that builds a mysql query depending on what values drop lists have?

If nothing is chosen in a drop list, then the drop list value is 001 so then the query should not include this drop list in the search!

Please help...

I have this so far:

```
            foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != '001') {
                 Do something smart...like add to a query...
                     }
        }
```

Comment: what do you have so far? You haven't given anyone anything to work with... what does your manual query look like? what does the html look like?

Comment: also why is this tagged perl?

Comment: If you explicity set the option's value to nothing <option value="">[Select Something]</option> then nothing will get sent to the server in case that helps.

Comment: You may consider ORM-like solutions, that give you proper level of abstraction and allow you to achieve what you requested (adding elements of the query) in a very clean way.

Answer (score 1):

Send the form to a PHP file called (say) script.php with method GET (or POST, if you prefer - in which case replace the references to GET below):

In script.php include the following:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['yourdroplistname']) {
  $value = 001;
} else {
  $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['yourdroplistname']);
}
mysql_query("YOUR QUERY, CONTAINING $value WHERE APPROPRIATE");
?>
```

Comment: Never use direct user input to construct raw SQL query. Use a placeholder variable, escape special characters in the value or cast it to int to make sure it contains a number.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a `switch($droplist)` to filter what PHP should do.

```
switch($droplist)
case '1':
$query = 'SELECT 1 FROM xy WHERE userid = 1';
break;
case '2':
// etc.
```